# IP conflict on macOS High Sierra: find log with hardware address of conflicting device

Tags: networking, ip-address, macos-sierra, wired, logfiles

I am on a university network with a computer running macOS High Siera that has its IP address assigned via DHCP.

On a regular basis (1 or 2 times a week), I lose all network connectivity for several hours and get the following error message when it starts:

```
Another device on the network is using your computer's IP address (<IP>).
```

Is there any log file on my client machine in which I can see the hardware address of the device that is stealing my IP address?

(Note: I know about other options, like checking on the switch, from another computer, etc. My question is specifically about a log file on the computer which got kicked out of the network. I tried *Utilities -> Console.App* and using grep on the log directory, searching for the name of the network interface and its IP address, but could not find anything that seems relevant.)

Comment: This is a question you should be asking your IT support.

Comment: @DavidPostill I did, but they say they are not responsible because our working group is running macOS. They also said they can look up the hardware address of the conflicting device in a log file under Windows, and suggested I check whether I could do the same under macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You very likely won't find any direct information on the other computer in any logs.

What you need is *your* computer's IP address just before the error message. If this address is still visible somewhere, fine. If it's not, search the logs for the last IP address you had (or try re-acquiring a DHCP lease). If this also doesn't work, do `brew install dhcpdump`, let it run in a terminal window and look at what addresses you (and possibly other computers) got.

Once you have the contested IP address, make sure your machine doesn't use this IP address, ping the IP address (which then will go to the offending machine), and then use `arp` to find out the hardware address of the other machine.